# У меня нет Available environment groups в CentOS 6.7

Tags: linux, centos

При выполнении `yum grouplist` первое что показывает Installed Groups, но Available environment groups у меня отсутствует (хочу установить Basic Web Server)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1. текст лучше вставлять в вопрос как текст, а не изображение. 2. посмотрел на имеющемся centos-е 6.4: раздела *available environment groups* действительно нет. есть *available groups* и *available language groups*. и группы *basic web server* тоже нет. есть группа *web server*. 3. похоже, вы привели лишь малую часть выдаваемого командой списка.